# Original motherboard component + redesigned PCB = Well working?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, motherboard

Well I bought my laptop about 3 years ago, and I want to replace motherboard.

I have a nice Micro-ATX board, but as I know, this desktop motherboard cannot fit in laptop.

So I'm planning to figure out all the connections in original motherboard, re-design PCB to

make it fit in my laptop, and then transplant all the components.

Is there any possible problems in this plan? (except problems about soldering)

Comment: If you're asking this question, there is pretty much no way you'll be able to do it.

Comment: If the motherboard of your laptop is broken, you could maybe fix it. That would be a much better solution(if it is the thing you want).

Answer (score 3):

Redesigning a PC motherboard would take vastly more time and money than just buying a new laptop. The board has many layers and hundreds (if not thousands) of traces. You will not be able to figure out all of the connections. Even if you could, you would probably not be able to buy all of the same components unless you desolder them from the old board. That requires a hot air workstation and experience with surface-mount technology. The workstation will cost hundreds or thousands of dollars.

If you somehow design a new board by yourself (which would take a *long* time), you will need to build it. Prototype boards of that size and complexity can cost thousands of dollars. Once you get the board, you will probably find that it doesn't work very well. Gigahertz-class signals require special layout techniques.

Like Matt said: if you have to ask the question, you can't do it. It's like trying to build your own skyscraper because you want a bigger house.

Comment: The proposed re-packaging exercise would even be a huge project for the team of senior design engineers at the company that built the micro-ATX board in the first place!!! And even at that, they would have access to the board schematics, all the component footprint models, all the layout design rules PLUS they would have access to the parts crib to pull parts for the prototype. Adam is right. Buy a newer laptop.

Comment: Another thing you haven't thought about is heat. Your micro-ATX motherboard uses a heatsink/fan to cool the CPU - how are you going to do that in a laptop case which doesn't allow airflow out of it?